# No found page (express 4 + body-parser + form + post)

Tags: javascript, forms, post, express-4, body-parser

I want to receive data from client, so I use express 4 and middleware body-parser. 
But I input url:*localhost:5555/book*, page show the message: **Name: undefined**,
and I input url:*localhost:5555/book/form.html*, page show the message **Cannot POST /book/form.html**.
Here is my code.

form.html

```
<form action='./book' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='fred'>
    <input type='text' name='tel' value='0926xxx572'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/book', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.tel);

    res.send('Name: '+req.body.name);
    res.send('country: '+req.body.tel);
    res.end();

});

app.listen(5555);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you're doing a `app.post` on the route `/book` so express expects a POST request.

But when you go to the url `http://localhost:5555/book` you are doing a GET request, thus the error.

There should be one page (a GET request therefore a `app.get`) for displaying the form and one page for accepting post requests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use html ，I replaced by jade.
And I use app.route().

form.jade

```
form(action='./book' method='post')
input(type='text' name='name' value='fred')
input(type='text' name='tel' value='0926xxx572')
input(type='submit' value='Submit')
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.route('/book')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    //res.send('Get a random book');
    res.render('form');
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Name: '+req.body.name +'<br>'+ 'tel: '+req.body.tel);
  })

app.listen(5555);
```